# Mysql Table verticle merge

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Mysql tables which contains some data. Both of the tables have a common field type and name called 'Time' but other fields in the both tables will be called something different.

I would like to generate a query where I could retrieve data from both tables so I could plot the data to a chart.

```
Table1
-------
Time                    ColA1   ColA2
2018-06-11 09:23:23     1.5     1.8    
2018-06-11 09:43:24     2.3     3.4    
2018-06-11 09:45:24     3.3     3.4



Table2
-------
Time                    ColB1   ColB2    
2018-06-11 09:25:23     3.5     2.8    
2018-06-11 09:41:24     5.3     4.4
```

I would like to achieve the output as:

```
    ----
Time                    Col A1  ,Col A1 , ColB1 ,   ColB2
2018-06-11 09:23:23     1.5     ,1.8    ,   Null,   Null    
2018-06-11 09:25:23     Null    ,Null   ,   3.5 ,   2.8    
2018-06-11 09:41:24     Null    ,Null   ,   5.3 ,   4.4    
2018-06-11 09:43:24     2.3     ,3.4    ,   Null,   Null    
2018-06-11 09:45:24     3.3     ,3.4    ,   Null,   Null
```

Comment: It's probably easier to read without all `&#09;`s

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it now. I was just trying to show tabs and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from 
( 
    select t1.time, t1.colA1, t1.colA2, null as ColB1, null as ColB2 from table1 t1
    union all
    select t2.time, null, null, t2.ColB1, t2.ColB2 from table2 t2
) tmp
order by time
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem, Much appreciated for quick response!